# How to make a transition when upper div is removed

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

I would like to know how to make a transition up of one div when an upper DIV is removed... I know there are many questions about it but they all use Jquery and i dont want to use it. How can i do this?

For example:

```
<div class='father'>
   <div class='child'>
   <div class='child'>
   <div class='child'>
   <div class='child'>
<div>
```

When the upper child is removed of the DOM, the other divs have a transition up... Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as simple as adding a `transition` to the `.child` class. It depends on how you are removing the upper div. 
here's an example

```css
.child {
  height: 200px;
  background: #666;
  border: 1px solid;
  transition: 1s;
}
#top:hover {
  height: 0;
}
#next {
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="child" id="top">hover over this div to hide it</div>
  <div class="child" id="next">this div will move up</div>
</div>
```